# How do I combine multiple kinesis data streams into 1 data stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, stream, amazon-kinesis

I have data coming in from 3 different servers(3 data streams). Is it possible to merge these data (kind of update/upsert) in kinesis consumer application and get the updated data as output?

The data I have from stream 2,3 is dependent on stream 1. For example

> Stream 1 (ItemDetails) - {itemId, itemName, itemdescription}, 
>  stream
>   2 (ItemtoCart) - {ItemId}, 
>  stream 3 (Itemordered) - {ItemId}.

Final Stream output I am expecting is

> OutputStream - {itemId, itemName, itemdescription, itemtoCart_flag,
>   itemOrdered_flag}

Stream 1 is receiving the data at the rate of 10K records/sec.

Comment: Are you saying you want to merge your three data streams into one stream?? Stream can't update your events, it should not. What you can do is whenever theres event in any of the 3 streams, consume it and have a logic how you want to have a state somewhere in datastores like MongoDB or Cassandra, whatever. So, your MongoDB state is the final output you want.

Answer (score 1):

Say there are three streams as below,

```
stream                   event in stream
stream1(ItemPurchased) - {"item" : 1, "totalQuantity": 100}

stream2(ItemOrdered)   - {"item" : 1, "sold": 1}

stream3(ItemCancelled) - {"item" : 1, "orderCancelled": 1}
```

The streams are for Item purchase, then sold and or cancelled.

Say, I wanna build a final state of item available quantity from these events.
What I would do is,

- consume each event in stream  / kinesis has lambda functionality but not sure how easily it talks to non aws datastores like MongoDB, Cassandra
- and have a logic to build a final state based on event

**State transition table**

```
stream                   events                                  consumer/onEvent          state (could be MongoDB, Cassandra)
stream1(ItemPurchased) - {"item" : 1, "totalQuantity": 100}   -> create new state      -> {"item" : 1, "availableQuantity": 100} 

stream2(ItemOrdered)   - {"item" : 1, "sold": 1}              -> decrease the quantity -> {"item" : 1, "availableQuantity": 100 - 1} 

stream3(ItemCancelled) - {"item" : 1, orderCancelled: 1}      -> increase the quantity -> {"item" : 1, "availableQuantity": 99 + 1}
```

Hope that answers your question, but unlike you asked it is the final state table not a stream.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I have edited the question as what is my input and what I am expecting as output.